# How can I use Qt5 with ROS kinetic?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am a beginner with ROS and I want to do GUI for control my robotic arm. I think that I can use Qt5 in ROS without any plugins or changing some settings in QtCreator. I want to test a simple GUI with "Hello world" button but I have no idea how to do CMakeLists.txt and package.xml for my package. Can you show me how should I do CMakeLists.txt and package.xml? Thank you

Here is my package's path:

catkin_ws/src/gui

- gui.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt
- package.xml

I have no idea if it works but here is my idea of simple "Hello world button" program
gui.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <ros/ros.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv, "gui");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   QApplication app (argc, argv);

   QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
   button.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277163/how-can-i-use-qt5-with-ros-kinetic?/) by [Zenzu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32843/zenzu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2017-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [roscreate-qt-pkg](http://wiki.ros.org/qt_create/Tutorials/Qt%20App%20Templates), it is very easy.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0